# Location not found on flyway migrate on websphere

Tags: java, spring, websphere, flyway

I'm trying to setup flyway-migration on Websphere server.

My project consists of  the modules:

```
 --projectwar.war
     --projectsql.jar
          --java
              --MyFlywayUtil.class
          -- resources
               -- myscripts
     --projectmodel.jar
           --java
                --MyRiskDataSourceConfig.class
```

MyRiskDataSourceConfig contains flyway migration declaration:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
public Flyway flyway(@Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
    flyway.setClassLoader(MyFlywayUtil.class.getClassLoader());
    flyway.setLocations("classpath:"+"myscripts");
    flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return flyway;
}
```

When executed under Tomcat using bootRun comand, migration works fine and location is found.

However under Websphere I receive the following:

```
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@bb6f8b91[app]
Local ClassPath 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/cell01/project.ear/project.war/WEB-INF/classes 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/cell01/project.ear/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/projectmodel.jar 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/cell01/project.ear/project.war/WEB-INF/lib/projectsql.jar 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/cell01/project.ear/project.war 

Parent com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@c26663d6 Delegation Mode  PARENT_FIRST) 
On WebSphere an empty file named flyway.location must be present on the classpath location for WebSphere to find it!
o.f.c.i.u.s.classpath.ClassPathScanner Unable to resolve location classpath myscripts
```

I've tried configuration with and without flyway.setClassLoader();

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Did you also add an (empty) file with the name `flyway.location` to the folder(s) containing your migrations, in my cases this fixed the problem.

Because of the way the IBM class-loader works this file has to be added as a workaround, see also the [source](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/2cb27f21f5356633db18a992aebab0b37994f3da/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/scanner/classpath/ClassPathScanner.java#L221)

And of course the warning which is given:

> On WebSphere an empty file named flyway.location must be present on the classpath location for WebSphere to find it!

Comment: Wow, what a piece of dirty code. Thanks for a hint, will check later on

Comment: Worked for me. I am using flyway 5.2.4 
My flyway location is configured in application.properties like this:  
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/flywaymigration  .
So I just put the empty flyway.location file there and then WAS could find them.  
Thanks for the solution, saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [git issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1301), the problem was fixed in flyway 4.0.1

Comment: I'm using a version 4.2.0