# Flyway: no migration necessary

Tags: java, spring, flyway

There is a database that is used by a Spring-based application.
The database isn't versioned by the Flyway.

I have added the flyway-related beans to the spring configuration:

```
<bean id="flywayConfig" class="org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.ClassicConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="true" />
        <property name="schemas" value="DB2INST1,SRVO"/>
        <property name="locations">
                <value>classpath:db</value>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
        <constructor-arg ref="flywayConfig"/>
</bean>
```

I've placed a migration script for testing purpose in:

```
src/main/resouces/db/V1.1__create.sql
```

It creates a table in `SRVO` schema.

However after the app start I can see that the table

`flyway_schema_history` has been created and contains only one entry

```
installed_rank|version|description          |type    |script               
--------------|-------|---------------------|--------|---------------------
             1|1      |<< Flyway Baseline >>|BASELINE|<< Flyway Baseline >>
```

Why has the script not been applied? I haven't noticed any errors in the server log. Below is the excerpt from it related to Flyway:

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Scanning for classes at classpath:db
org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory - Database: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SRVO (DB2/LINUXX8664 11.5)
org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory - Driver  : IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ 4.13.127
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway - DDL Transactions Supported: true
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway - Schemas: DB2INST1,SRVO
org.flywaydb.core.Flyway - Default schema: null
org.flywaydb.core.internal.callback.SqlScriptCallbackFactory - Scanning for SQL callbacks ...
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Validating migrations ...
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.012s)
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "DB2INST1": 1
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema "DB2INST1" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Comment: Shouldn't those scripts be in `src/main/resources/db/migration`?

Comment: @sp00m why should they if I explicitly specify the path?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't pay attention to the configuration to be honest.

Comment: `src/main/resouces/db/V1.1__create.sql` - is this a new sql - or you've updated an existing sql script? Migrations require newly versioned scripts... you cannot modify an existing script and have it run as that's not how it works. Not sure if this is your issue as we don't know the earlier state of the DB before you run the migration

Comment: It's a new script. I've just noticed in the server log `org.flywaydb.core.internal.scanner.classpath.ClassPathScanner - Unable to resolve location classpath:db` What is the correct syntax for the path?

Comment: You could remove this setting and just use the default `resources/db/migration` for your sql scripts ?

Comment: See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#discovery and https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations#maven - your `resouces` is missing an `r` - perhaps just a small typo? either in what you wrote above or a dir you manually created?

Comment: Also worth using a consistent format: `<property name="locations" value="classpath:db" />`

Comment: Wow. It was long... However @RobEvans you was right when you wrote that something was wrong with the location. I removed the related configuration completely and moved the script to the standard location. But it wasn't enough. I also had to put an empty file `flyway.location` in db/migration so that Websphere could detect it...

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57075714/971355
Not sure whether I have to remove the question or not. When I asked it I didn't expect that the cause would be so unexpected. Thanks anyway for pointing me to the problem with location.

Comment: That's a really odd requirement.... maybe don't use IBM Websphere lol ;P

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies with the way you define schemas for Flyway. From what I see you define two schemas like so:

`<property name="schemas" value="DB2INST1,SRVO"/>`

And this is correctly picked up by Flyway as can be seen by these logs:

`org.flywaydb.core.Flyway - Schemas: DB2INST1,SRVO`

I can also see that the migration does run correctly **but** it does so for the `DB2INST1` schema and not `SRVO` -- which I think is the one you want to create the table at.

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "DB2INST1": 1
org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema "DB2INST1" is up to date. No migration necessary
```

Since you defined both schemas like so, Flyway will by default attempt to perform the migration on the first found schema (considered to be the default) as stated here:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/schemas

So your choices are two:

1. Remove the `DB2INST1` schema from the list of schemas (not really sure if you want Flyway to manage it)
2. Set the default schema to `SRVO` explicitly using this configuration property: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/defaultSchema

I hope the above help.